# Regex expression to remove house number unless it has letters as well

Tags: javascript, regex, street-address

I have two addresses

1. 226 W 750 S should equal **W 750 S**
2. 5th Avenue East Unit#B32c should equal **5th Avenue East**

With this Regex **^\d+|Unit.+|(.+)|or\s.+|#.+|,.+|.$** I get

1. W 750 S - **Correct**
2. th Avenue East - **Incorrect**

With this Regex **s-\d+|Unit.+|(.+)|or\s.+|#.+|\d+\s|\d+\w{1}\s|\d+\w{1}$** I get

1. W S - **Incorrect**
2. 5th Avenue East - **Correct**

Can anyone help adjust either expression to fit both situations.

Thanks for any help!!

Comment: why not match them separately?

Comment: Can you add also some expression that should not match?

Comment: I'm pretty new to regex so trying to modify "s-\d+|Unit.+|(.+)|or\s.+|#.+|\d+\s|\d+\w{1}\s|\d+\w{1}$" to fit both situations.  I'm open to matching separately but when I try it screws up another address format.

Comment: Why is it correct to have `Unit#B32c` missing?

Comment: It's for display purposes only on a postcard.

Answer (score 0):

This would work:

```
^\d+(?![a-zA-Z])\s*|\s*Unit.+
```

https://regex101.com/r/F0PjEN/1

Comment: "This would work" is not really helpful and convincing. What if the user puts it into a RegExp constructor? Why do you think the pattern must work?

Answer (score 0):

I appreciate the suggestions. This is what I went with and works with several other address formats.  I probably have extra stuff in here but it works.

`^[^#th]\d+|Unit.+|.-|\(([^)]+)\)|or\s.+|#.+|\d+\w{1}$`